# В чем ошибка? Не работает условие в цикле

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, олимпиада, условия

Задача:
Миша записал по 100 слов КОТ и РОТ в некоторый текстовый файл (файл problem4.txt), а затем случайно сделал замены некоторых символов Р на К, но забыл, каких конкретно. Определите, сколькими способами Миша может вернуть файл к исходному виду. Способом восстановления файла Миша называет выбор некоторого количества слов, в которых он сделает обратную замену, чтобы текстовый файл снова содержал 100 слов КОТ и 100 слов РОТ. Порядок, в котором Миша выбирает слова, не имеет значения.

код:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string c[200],a;
    int rot=0,kot=0;

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
        cin>>a;
        if(a=="КОТ")
            kot+=1;
        else
            rot+=1;

        c[i]=a;
    }
    cout<<kot-rot;
}
```

[Файл](https://my-files.su/Save/sygtm1/problem4.txt)

При вводе 200 слов, срабатывает 1 условие на все слова, заранее спасибо

Comment: Массив вам не нужен, достаточно счётчиков. Ввод разве не из файла должен быть?

Comment: Да, из файла, но т.к. не умел, решил не морочиться, поэтому просто скопировал все слова из файла и вводил их через cin

Comment: Так что происходит, если вы вводите, например, по два слова каждого вида? Выведите a для контроля

Comment: Во-первых, вам нужно *количество способов*, а не разница `kot-rot`, а во-вторых, у вас кодировка файла — UTF8... Если использовать ту же кодировку и для исходника, то все получается.

Comment: Да, а после того как вы получите свои 10, т.е. 105-95, останется выяснить, сколькими способами можно выбрать 5 котов из 105...